# Problem with add_rewrite_tag

Tags: functions, url-rewriting

I tried to rewrite my URl with a custom query string. 
Here is the code :

```
add_action( 'init', 'wpse12065_init' );
function wpse12065_init()
{
    add_rewrite_rule(
        'resultat-2/([^/]*)/([^/]*)',
        'index.php?pagename=resultat-2&cat=$matches[2]&ville=$matches[1]',
        'top'
    );
}

function custom_rewrite_tag() {
        add_rewrite_tag('%cat%', '([^&]+)');
        add_rewrite_tag('%ville%', '([^&]+)');
    }
    add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_tag', 10, 0);
```

The problem is that when I try to get the value of the tag 'cat', the non-numeric chars are ignored and i don't know why because I never specified that. And all works normally with the tag 'ville'.

Can somebody help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cat` is a reserved query variable used for the ID of a post category.

To avoid conflicts with WordPress and/or other plugins and themes I'd recommend you 'namespace' your query variables eg `eddh_cat` instead of `cat`